# How to retrieve data from many to many Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables
1. Course
2.User.

User can choose course from list of courses and with his entity he can save his user information. Now an Admin can check the user details.so, there is a user details  page in there i want to show user details. But it's not

Here is the User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table='users';
     protected $fillable=['name','email','phone','course_id'];
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
    }
}
```

Here is the Course Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table='courses';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

      public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','course_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Fee;
use App\Course;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function getStudentDetails(){
        // $user = User::all();
        $user = \DB::table('users')->where('course_id','!=',0) ->get(); 
         return view('studentDetails', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

I have  to show only those users data who have selected the courses from list. How could i do it?

Comment: I didn't get what users you want to show. "who have selected the courses from list in user details page" What do you mean?

Comment: you have a little space before the ->get()   / i didnt get what are you trying to do to but try  $user = User::where('course_id', 1)->get();

Comment: User have already selected list of courses from the courses tables and complete the registraiton .And now i want to show this user details some other page with course name and to show i need to check with course table also. because in user table i only saved id of courses not name.
@Erick

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja will it be checking only for the course_id = 1..right?

Comment: now its clear, there is the answer by shuvrow! next time try to better explain and you will get help faster and with ease :)

Comment: Ooh..ok ..i'll try! 
thanks! @AchrafKhouadja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get User data in controller:

```
$user=User::with('courses')->first();
```

In view, check if a user has a course , before tr, in tbody use this condition

```
<tbody>
@foreach($user as $row)
@if($row->courses)<tr><td></td></tr>
@endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Then access course name by using this code

```
{{ $row->courses->name }}
```